# Typescript - Pass interface literals to function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use an interface to set the data types and then call them in the function while setting a **default value** if they are not passed through.

I get an error of `',' expected.` after canvas in the function. Can't I call it in this way?

```
// Options
interface options {
    canvas?: {
        width: number;
        height: number;
        bgColor: string;
    };
    brushes?: {
        sizeSm: number;
        sizeLg: number;
    };
}

function initialize(options {canvas.width = 700, brushes.sizeSm = 20}) {
    // Do stuff
}

// Call function
initialize({
    canvas: {
        width: 820,
        height: 450,
        bgColor: '#fff'
    },
    brushes: {
        sizeSm: 10,
        sizeLg: 20
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be working

```
interface options {
    canvas?: {
        width: number;
        height?: number;
        bgColor?: string;
    };
    brushes?: {
        sizeSm: number;
        sizeLg?: number;
    };
}

function initialize(opts: options = {canvas : { width : 700}, brushes: {sizeSm : 20}} ) {
//function initialize(options {canvas.width = 700, brushes.sizeSm = 20}) {
    // Do stuff
}

// Call function
initialize({
    canvas: {
        width: 820,
        height: 450,
        bgColor: '#fff'
    },
    brushes: {
        sizeSm: 10,
        sizeLg: 20
    },
});
```

Firstly, the syntax of the options as a paramter should be adjusted to consume the interface **`opts: options`**.

Next, if we want want to have a `default value`, we need to properly pass it:

```
function initialize(opts: options = {canvas : { width : 700}, brushes: {sizeSm : 20}} ) {
```

And because we set only width and sizeSm .. the rest is adjusted to be optional *(e.g. `heigth?:number`)*

Play with that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20options%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20canvas%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bgColor%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20brushes%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sizeSm%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sizeLg%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20initialize(opts%3A%20options%20%3D%20%7Bcanvas%20%3A%20%7B%20width%20%3A%20700%7D%2C%20brushes%3A%20%7BsizeSm%20%3A%2020%7D%7D%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2Ffunction%20initialize(options%20%7Bcanvas.width%20%3D%20700%2C%20brushes.sizeSm%20%3D%2020%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20stuff%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Call%20function%0D%0Ainitialize(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20canvas%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20820%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3A%20450%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bgColor%3A%20'%23fff'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20brushes%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sizeSm%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sizeLg%3A%2020%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Wow, this looks like what I'm after. Of course, I have to set the parameter to the interface. One thing, I've done as above and I'm getting `Identifier expected` for the values, e.g. `{width : 700}`.

Comment: because you've used this `function initialize(options {canvas : { width : 700}... ` and this is wrong.. because we miss the interface as a type. we need that (as in my answer) `function initialize(opts: options = {canvas : { width : 700}`. the `opts` is variable name, the `:options` is type and after `=` we can see the default value.. hope that helps a bit ;)